# NetBeans IDE -java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

When trying to run my program in netbeans , I get the following error `"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: be/abeel/io/GZIPPrintWriter"`.There are no problems reported in the code. ALSO, the error was connected with the line of the following code :

```
 Dataset data = FileHandler.loadDataset(new File("Book10.data"), noFeatures, ",");
```

P.S. NetBeans 7.4

Comment: Maybe this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) or a bug in netbeams?

Comment: thanks@paper1111. from the error i may missed a class from my classpath, which seems to be part of the project but I could not know which class. Could someone provide more help?thanks